# How to change Dialtone sound in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio

I am planning on using the Dialer App plugin using Phonegap for both Android and iOS. As of now I have created a dialer app for Android using ( https://github.com/sialam/PhoneGap-2.7-Android-plugins-to-make-a-phone-call ).

Now I need to know how to programmatically have a custom music for the dialtone. 
As of now (default android function)

1. User punches in phone number and presses call button
2. The calling process begins and a ring is heard (the transition from step 2) to step 3) can be noticed visibly while performing a call on android)
3. User picks up call or user busy recording is played

What I want

1. User punches in phone number and presses call button
2. As the calling process begins a custom audio / music is played till the ring, the ring need not be replaced by the custom audio.
3. User picks up call or user busy recording is played

I need a similar functionality on iPhone, but I don't know the steps since I don't own an iPhone.

Comment: Dialtone is provided by cellular provider.

Comment: You definitely can't do this on an iPhone - as soon as you launch the phone app to place a call your app has no control

Comment: @Raptor I have edited the question, is there a way to put music up till the ring, the ring need not be replaced by music.

Comment: @Paulw11 Raptor The actual program dials to a particular phone and that phone dials the actual number. So if I enter 123456, it calls another phone 654321 and then from the phone 654321 it dials 123456. While the user hears, he notices the initial dialtone then the intermediate phone rings and he notices the dialtone of the intermediate phone and then the destination number 123456 is dialed and he hears the final ringtone. I want to hide the intermediate dialtone and intermediate ringtone from the user. Please suggest a way

Comment: There is no way on iOS. Once you have started a call the phone app is in control

Comment: @joel since you've no control on iPhone's Phone App (except for input the phone number), you can't work it out in iOS. Even native iOS SDK can't achieve this. If you're using VOIP like Skype, you still have a chance to do so.